# Can we use taylor series to solve difficult equations (example with cos(x)=x)?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Well I saw that the curve of the taylor function series of $\cos(x)$ at $x=0$ marry (it's a french expression to say that is very very near) the curve of $\cos(x)$ between $x=0$ and $x=pi/2$

So if I have a lot of terms of this series and I solve the equation, have I the solution ?

Example : $ \cos(x)\underset{x \to 0}=1-\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} o(x^2)$

[image]

If I solve $x=1-x^2/2+x^4/24$ I find $x=x = 0.73921922...$ (x is positive for \cos(x)) and with my computer I find $x=0.739085... $

Can we do that with all real function?

Shadock

Comment: Informal English terms that are sometimes used include kiss and hug. One doesn't necessarily marry.

Comment: Note that what you have described looks like $$0=1-\frac {x^2}2+\frac {x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}-x+O(x^8)$$ which should be easy to approximate...  You can even approximate with three terms, then with four, and then take the average between the two...

Comment: All functions, no. I think direct imitation with $x=\tan x$ would not work out well.

Comment: I would like to know the mistake i do when i do that and if there is better way to solve it?

Comment: Once you get a good estimate, just keep applying the cosine function to that, over and over. That works.

Comment: Well that's a good idea but i seek a best way because it's not easy to solve polynomial equations, newton's method is good but well i don't find it terrific so...

Comment: The Newton Method is usually pretty terrific. I like a relative, the Secant Method. But best are optimized Fortran (yes!) root-finding routines.

Comment: @Shadock. Having such a name, you must be French. Am I right ? If yes, where are you ?

Comment: @AndréNicolas. Nice to hear you telling good things about Fortran. This is a language I learnt $54$ years ago and I still use it on a daily basis. I even dream in Fortran ! Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, for solving $x=\cos(x)$, you expand $\cos(x)$ as a Taylor series up to order $n$, you will need to solve a polynomial of degree close to $n$ which is not an easy task and the result will depend on the value you select fo $n$.

Let us call $x_n$ the solution obtained for the Taylor expansion of $\cos(x)$. The results will then be $$x_1=1$$ $$x_2=x_3=0.732051$$ $$x_4=x_5=0.739219$$ $$x_6=x_7=0.739084$$ $$x_8=x_9=0.739085$$ which is the solution for six significant figures. But, to reach this level of accuracy, you had to solve an high degree polynomial for which there is almost no analytical solution (except for very low values of $n$).

As mentioned in the comments, it is much easier to use a simple root-finder as Newton which, starting from a "reasonable" guess $x_0$ will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ Let us be very lazy and start at $x_0=1$. The successive iterates will then be : $0.750364$, $0.739113$, $0.739085$. The solution has been obtained with very simple algebra and without the need of solving any polynomial.

If we take advantage of the second solution obtained solving a quadratic $x_0=0.732051$, the successive iterates will then be : $0.739096$, $0.739085$ which show that we only saved one Newton iteration but had to solve first $-\frac{x^2}{2}-x+1=0$.